# how to use opencv-python in jython？

Tags: java, python, opencv, jython

I need to use my opencv-python program as a jar in JAVA's environment anywhere

but whatever I change `sys.path` or download opencv again it occurred：
[image: error]

I just use `pip install opencv,numpy` at the workdir, and it work well in a computer with python but any moudles

I can import opencv if I open python in the workdir but any other path

[test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFL3q.png)

**I just want to know how jython can find my opencv moudle in the workdir just like a .py can import other .py in same dir**

Comment: What's your error information? can u paste it here?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<iostream>", line 5, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/imutils/__init__$py.class", line 8, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/imutils/convenience$py.class", line 6, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/cv2/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/Users/ss/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named cv2

Comment: You have no install opencv success, check it by `pip freeze`, see if you have install it.

Comment: jpython has an independent environment, if you like to run your app un jPython, should install OpenCV on your jPython again!

Comment: `pip freeze` can't list my moudles becaese i use `pip install target` to install opencv and numpy,etc to my workdir. I can import them if i open python in the workdir and other path can't

Comment: You should run all your app on `virtualenv`, try to install one and then you will get away from trouble! `sudo pip install virtualenv`

Comment: thanks for ur patience ，but i can't use `virtualenv` or install opencv in jython for some reasons, so I need to know how jython can find my opencv moudle in the workdir just like a .py can import other .py in same dir

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Jython does not support third-party Python libraries that use extensions written in C. That said the java version of OpenCV is solid.

Comment: It does seem like some more advanced features are missing though. It is quite good as you say but there may be things you need not implemented.